# PHP mail send to multiple recipients, I must be doing something wrong

Tags: php, email

I read the other questions and solutions... which is why I'm frustrated.  I didn't code this app, but I'm trying to retrofit it.

Currently it sends a confirmation email to the email address that gets entered by the customer in the field.  When I comment out the mail($to,... part at the bottom, it breaks the confirmation email functionality, so I know I'm in the right place in the code.

I just want a duplicate email sent to my master email address.  I thought if I just put another mail command under the functional one, but specified a static address instead of the $to var it would work... but it doesn't.  I couldn't get the CC header functionality to work either based on other questions, so I thought just sending a duplicate email to another address would work just fine.

Here is the working code:

```
$sq2 = myQuery(" select * from admin  ");
$dat2 = mysql_fetch_object($sq2);

$from = "reservations@duelingpianopiano.com";
$to = $email;

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers

$headers .= "From: $from" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $from" . "\r\n";

/*$headers = "From: $from" . "\r\n" .

    "Reply-To: $from" . "\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();*/


mail("vmvijitha@gmail.com", $subject, "sendemailtemplate($templateid,$tid,$userid,$modification)".$mailcontent, $headers);

//return;

mail($to, $subject, $mailcontent, $headers);
```

I feel like if I should just be able to add this line at the bottom to send the exact same email confirmation redundantly to my master email address for safe keeping.

`mail("reservations@duelingpianopiano.com", $subject, $mailcontent, $headers);`

Note: I think this line is an artifact from the original developer, and I can't tell whether it's working or not.
 `mail("vmvijitha@gmail.com", $subject,...`

What am I assuming wrong?

Answer (score 0):

insert multiple addresses using comma-separator in single variable.

```
$email_to = "xxx@one.com, xxx@two.com, xxx@three.com"

mail($email_to, $subject, $mailcontent, $headers);
```

Comment: Thank you, how would I do it when the primary email address is already a var?
`$to = $email, "to@me.com";`

Comment: Where you are geetting this $email var ?

Comment: I wish I knew exactly, but it comes from a user filled web form, then stored in a MySQL DB, so I don't know exactly how it's formatted.